# Trying to count left nodes in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I have some cases passing with this code but others are failing.. is it my logic or is it the order of if statements..please help.. using practiceitcs website

```
public int countLeftNodes() {

    return countLeftNodes(overallRoot);
}

private int countLeftNodes(IntTreeNode root){

    int count = 0;

    if (root== null) return count;
    if (root.right == null && root.left == null)
        return count;

    if(root.right != null)  count += countLeftNodes(root.left);

    if (root.left!= null)
        count += 1 + countLeftNodes(root.left);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Indentation and formatting, please. And look closely at your code - if the node has both left and right children, you're counting twice the number of left nodes in the left child. You're never counting the number of left nodes of the *right child*. Can you spot where your logic has gone wrong?

Comment: LEFT means "LEFT SIDE" or "REMAINING"?